# Error send a form with Ajax.BeginForm at ASPNET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an form at aspnet mvc with use the helper Ajax.BeginForm, but when I summit the form I have the following error at the console:

**Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for='[0].Selected'], label[for='[0].Selected *', #[0].Selected-error**

[image]

The code I have is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST");" new { @class = "custom" }))
{
    @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
    {
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.HiddenFor(i => i[index].SocialNetworkId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i[index].Selected)
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => i[index].Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" value="Update" id="btnSave">Save</button>
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The (default) `@Html.DisplayFor()` method does not take an argument for Html attributes. The second argument is for a template name.

Comment: Hi devqon, I changed the @Html.DisplayFor() but the error is the samen, thanks, another idea?

Comment: You also have a syntax error on `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST");" new { @class = "custom" }))`

Answer (score 0):

Please write the code like below

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("save", Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post"}, new { @class = "custom" }))
{
    @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
    {
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.HiddenFor(i => Model[index].SocialNetworkId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => Model[index].Selected)
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => Model[index].Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" value="Update" id="btnSave">Save</button>
}
```

You have used the **;** symbol in your ajax near by the **HttpMethod = "Post"** code, that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi Aravindan, thanks for your help, I try it but the error is the same.

Comment: Please do as i did in the updated code and let me know if you still face the same problem.

Comment: Hi Aravindan, I try your code but the error is the same.

Comment: Hi,anyone more has another idea? Thanks!

Comment: Let me know your Save action method please. Please update that code too.